# Why can't I connect to newly created database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

I just created a new database in phpMyAdmin for a new WordPress installation, but I get an error when testing connection:

> "Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'grow' (1)"

But when I test the default "mysql" db, it's successful.  Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROW` doesn't make any sense as a host name.  You want something like `localhost`, `dbserver14.example.com`, or `10.123.24.12`. Ask you hosting provider or MySQL person what the host name should be.